# Firefox Error on RtlpWorkerCallout

Tags: firefox

What would cause FireFox to crash with a signature of RtlpWorkerCallout, crash reason = EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION? I'm trying to figure out what feature or plugin would be involved.

The same problem seems to be causing trouble with IE, but not with Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a conflict with the Firewall portion of Trend Micro Antivirus. I didn't find a workaround. I switched to a different antivirus program.